# String data format

Tags: java, dataformat

May I ask a stupid question?

Please let me know if there is any special name (like json) for this kind of string data format.

```
time(HH:MM:SS.nnn) => some value(ex: 12345, predefined code.) : {key=value;key={key=value;key=value;};key=value;}
```

Something like this. (I'm not sure they are called key and value, they look like key and value. Like channel=0;type=A;)
This is log file generated by Java code.
It's bit hard to search it.

Thank you in advance!
-JESuh-

Comment: I have not seen that format before, so I don’t know a name for it. Could it be homegrown?

Comment: Are you able to access the application's logger configuration and include it in the question?